# How to dynamically generate UITextFleid based on my input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am developing an application which requires to generate the `UITextField` dynamically.That means If I enter the value is more than one in the `UITextField`, it should generate 2 `UITextField` dynamically.If you guys have an idea about this please suggest me.
I am tried like this first created 3 textFiled.two  textFiled hidden

```
one.hidden=YES;
two.hidden=YES;
```

in ViewDidload,and then it's show if I enter more than one in 3textFiled,

Thanks for your suggestions in advance for your replies and suggestions...

Comment: Do you two lines?  in one textview?

Comment: I am not understand your ?, add some details plz.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please look once my question

Comment: take a loop for your entered value (1, 2 ,3 ...maximum) and in that create textfield programmatically and add it as subview in self.view or where you need.

Comment: Take a look at `<objc/runtime.h>`. I remember that there're method to create instance dynamically. Otherwise, you can instantiate a typical UITextField, and copy it whenever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([yourtextfield.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"You Enter 1");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<[yourtextfield.text integerValue]; i++)
        {
            UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (i*30)+200, 200, 24)];
            txtField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            txtField.text = @"abc";
            [self.view addSubview:txtField];
        }
    }
```

if you need only two text field then put i<2

Comment: thanks for reply but when i place you code in textFieldDidBeginEditing .if i enter in textFlied it's showing .but when inter more then 2 in textFiled in that time only Visable other textFiled

Comment: Put code in textFieldShouldReturn not in textFieldDidBeginEditing.